# How to separate sampled data in two different groups

Tags: probability, statistics, python

I have data from experiments that I would like to differentiate into two zones.
The data represents the time between events, so the two zones represent events that occur faster and the other events that occur slower, and I would like to find a separation between the two.
The data comes from experiments, so some data can be easy to see visually where the separation approximately is, but in other experiments not so easy.

For example, the following example plotted with python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data1 = [0.8253909999999998, 0.8804020000000001, 0.14202099999999973, 0.7727520000000005, 1.1040220000000005, 0.10714699999999944, 0.5750040000000016, 0.7876929999999973, 0.8980040000000002, 1.1478490000000008, 0.44635099999999994, 1.052067000000001, 0.4327469999999991, 0.3272960000000005, 0.26918099999999967, 0.3854459999999982, 0.1827140000000007, 0.8867760000000011, 0.7774879999999982, 0.21082900000000038, 0.6758939999999996, 0.4335760000000022, 0.6791699999999992, 0.7758439999999993, 0.15755200000000258, 0.1414289999999987, 0.36975599999999886, 0.8993549999999999, 0.6577640000000002, 1.043728999999999, 0.19952800000000082, 0.12645200000000045, 0.3454990000000002, 0.9054520000000004, 0.7165229999999987, 0.9425269999999983, 0.7159280000000052, 0.7413279999999958, 0.12669900000000212, 0.2822880000000012, 0.3690029999999993, 0.7246340000000018, 0.4718329999999966, 0.7580859999999987, 0.744059, 0.19344999999999857, 0.12031900000000206, 0.47543600000000197, 0.437542999999998, 0.44232000000000227, 0.5250109999999992, 0.17673200000000122, 0.2440649999999991, 0.31524799999999686, 0.7674680000000009, 0.7837700000000041, 1.1910290000000003, 0.14404899999999543, 0.21560399999999902, 0.19931500000000568, 0.27113699999999596, 0.728234999999998, 0.5061920000000057, 0.6459329999999994, 0.7817450000000008, 0.8265129999999985, 0.17931199999999592, 0.30208600000000274, 0.32583699999999993, 0.41771599999999864]
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=data1, bins='auto', color='#0504aa',
                            alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.9,)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.35)
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Hit interval')
```

[image]

The separation value could be approximately at time=0.6 but with another experiment, for example,

```
data2 = [0.2571259999999995, 1.5822640000000003, 0.1466390000000004, 0.32824299999999873, 0.32104400000000055, 2.369047, 0.2478510000000007, 0.2485389999999974, 0.303955000000002, 0.2653870000000005, 2.5117650000000005, 0.3355749999999986, 0.292663000000001, 1.1105540000000005, 0.2860239999999976, 0.33515799999999984, 1.562253000000002, 0.28992900000000077, 0.2852049999999977, 0.34392700000000076, 1.8210219999999993, 0.329422000000001, 0.28030199999999894, 2.359422000000002, 0.2672719999999984, 0.24663200000000174, 0.2700189999999978, 0.3540030000000023, 1.2573369999999997, 0.5001749999999987, 0.310769999999998, 0.3096180000000004, 1.9164280000000034, 0.2525890000000004, 0.34174199999999644, 2.2837689999999995, 0.24895200000000273, 0.2644960000000012, 1.0374629999999954, 0.24909000000000248, 0.2702510000000018, 1.7076319999999967, 0.21309300000000064, 0.3227109999999982, 1.1984310000000065, 0.27072999999999325, 0.2533940000000001, 1.6089630000000028, 0.2667160000000024, 0.25072399999999817, 1.0275359999999978, 0.3001330000000024, 0.22650500000000306, 0.30086399999999713, 0.3070420000000027]
```

Visually, in a histogram representation seems more difficult to find separation,

[image]

I would like to find a way to compute the separation in two zones.

Comment: First rule for comparing - at least put on the same axis scale/range. You could argue that 0.5 is a difference in the latter plot, but plotting it on a better scale could give a bit indication.  Also why should there be 2 zones?

Comment: @Chinny84 If I understand the scale comment, the time values have different ranges. The data comes measuring blows to a boxing box. The experiment consists of doing two types of blows: at a faster frequency and a slower frequency. That is why two different zones. The problem is that different people do the test more professionally (data1) and others not so well (data2).

Comment: @pablo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513484/1d-number-array-clustering

Comment: @pablo Also, running a simple K-means with number of clusters=2 might help

Comment: So to be clear there are 2 cluster types - “professional” and “non-pro” and then within that you have fast and slow. It appears that you will get better results if you can identify pro and non-pro and build a model around that. Once again it depends on if you want to control for the quality vs the number of observations that you have.

Comment: @Chinny84 not exactly pro and not a pro. I have explained wrong. The numbers of data1 and data2 are times between events. There are moments of the experiment where the boxer gives several fast blows and rests between blows (these are the two types of events). In the first example, data1, up to time 0.6, are the fast sequence of blows, and times above 0.6 (approximately) are periods of rest between blows.